# Socket.IO Websocket Send message not working with Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, websocket, socket.io

I have a running server with apache and Socket.IO. I'm trying to send and receive message using socket.io on my website.

This is the code of my server:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var hskey = fs.readFileSync('file.key');
var hscert = fs.readFileSync('file.crt');

var options = {
    key: hskey,
    cert: hscert
};

var app = require('https').createServer(options);
var io = require('/usr/local/lib/node_modules/socket.io').listen(app);

app.listen(8181);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('serverMessage', 'Bienvenue master!');
socket.broadcast.emit('serverMessage', 'New user online');
});
```

And this is the webpage:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.io Test</title>
    <script src="./socket.io.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script>

    var socket;
    var firstconnect = true;

    function connect() {
      if(firstconnect) {
        socket = io.connect('https://secure.mysite.com:8181');

        socket.on('serverMessage', function(data){ message(data); });
        socket.on('connect', function(){ status_update("Connected to Server"); });
        socket.on('disconnect', function(){ status_update("Disconnected from Server"); });
        socket.on('reconnect', function(){ status_update("Reconnected to Server"); });
        socket.on('reconnecting', function( nextRetry ){ status_update("Reconnecting in " 
          + nextRetry + " seconds"); });
        socket.on('reconnect_failed', function(){ message("Reconnect Failed"); });

        firstconnect = false;
      }
      else {
        socket.socket.reconnect();
      }
    }

    function disconnect() {
      socket.disconnect();
    }

    function message(data) {
      document.getElementById('message').innerHTML += "<br>" + "Server says: " + data;
    }

    function status_update(txt){
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = txt;
    }

    function esc(msg){
      return msg.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
    }

    function send() {
      socket.send('clientMessage', 'world');    
    };        

    </script>

    <h1>Socket.io Test</h1>
    <div><p id="status">Waiting for input</p></div>
    <div><p id="message"></p></div>  
    <button id="connect" onClick='connect()'/>Connect</button>
    <button id="disconnect" onClick='disconnect()'>Disconnect</button>
    <button id="send" onClick='send()'/>Send Message</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Everything seems to work fine under Safari (websocket) and Opera (json pooling) but with Firefox and Chrome (websocket) I cannot send any message from the client to the server. Everything else is working, I can handshake, connect and gets server messages. I made allot of research but seems like I'm the only one with this problem.

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Had a look at "Browser Compatibility" for websockets here? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebSockets

Comment: Chrome might also have a different websockets implementation than standard webkit -- really not sure on this.

Comment: I used socket.io for websocket because it support also flashsocket, and long pooling so it should work but sending messages dosen't

Comment: socket.io allows you to select which transport is used (client-side) with configuration parameters, so play around with those to see which ones are available/connecting. What versions of Firefox & Chrome are you using? The compatibility information on the socket.io website says that they should be well supported, even if not by websockets.

Comment: You must have server configuration issues I've been using Socket.IO with Chrome/Firefox/IE using web/flashsockets for some time now; with no issues.

Comment: I didn't touch any of the server configuration it's socket.io default settings and sending message to server isn't working on firefox and chrome but everything else is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, I was using a different version of socket.io.js then the server side.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to check it. I'm also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

when you attach the socket.io module to express it intercepts the socket.io route.

So when you request "https://secure.mysite.com:8181/socket.io" it will respond with 
"Welcome to socket.io."

So when you request the client side socket.io.js it comes directly from the socket.io module.
"https://secure.mysite.com:8181/socket.io/socket.io.js"

So If you wan't to mod the client side library you could create a modified copy and let express serve up the file, but as you update socketio through npm you'll have to bump up your modified copy as well manually.

Answer (score 0):

if in FireFox you get this error - first check enabled or no proxy. and turnoff proxy if enabled.